# Convert variable to type only known at run-time?

Tags: c#

```
foreach (var filter in filters)
{
    var filterType = typeof(Filters);
    var method = filterType.GetMethod(filter, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    if (method != null)
    {
        var parameters = method.GetParameters();
        Type paramType = parameters[0].ParameterType;
        value = (string)method.Invoke(null, new[] { value });
    }
}
```

How can I cast `value` to `paramType`? `value` is a `string`, `paramType` will probably just be a basic type like `int`, `string`, or maybe `float`. I'm cool with it throwing an exception if no conversion is possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to lookup and invoke a .Net TypeConverter for a particular type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956076/how-to-lookup-and-invoke-a-net-typeconverter-for-a-particular-type)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to lookup and invoke a .Net TypeConverter for a particular type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956076/how-to-lookup-and-invoke-a-net-typeconverter-for-a-particular-type)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim's comment is a possible duplicate of the preceding one.

Comment: @kmote , the “possible duplicate” comment is usually automatically generated when someone vote to close the question as duplicate. Not sure why system inserted the same comment second time instead of increment vote of the first comment. May be the oldest comment was created manually, as it has low-case p in ‘possible’

Comment: @kmote, it is a known issue https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367526/merge-possible-duplicate-comments-and-votes

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The types you are using all implement `IConvertible`. As such you can use `ChangeType`.

```
 value = Convert.ChangeType(method.Invoke(null, new[] { value }), paramType);
```

Comment: awesome ... in single line.  var value = Convert.ChangeType(objectValue, objectType);

Answer (score 17):

You could go dynamic; for example:

```
using System;

namespace TypeCaster
{
    class Program
    {
        internal static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parent p = new Parent() { name = "I am the parent", type = "TypeCaster.ChildA" };
            dynamic a = Convert.ChangeType(new ChildA(p.name), Type.GetType(p.type));
            Console.WriteLine(a.Name);

            p.type = "TypeCaster.ChildB";
            dynamic b = Convert.ChangeType(new ChildB(p.name), Type.GetType(p.type));
            Console.WriteLine(b.Name);
        }
    }

    internal class Parent
    {
        internal string type { get; set; }
        internal string name { get; set; }

        internal Parent() { }
    }

    internal class ChildA : Parent
    {
        internal ChildA(string name)
        {
            base.name = name + " in A";
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return base.name; }
        }
    }

    internal class ChildB : Parent
    {
        internal ChildB(string name)
        {
            base.name = name + " in B";
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return base.name; }
        }
    }
}
```