# TypeConverter for property of Type object

Tags: c#, winforms, typeconverter

I need to display an object correctly in the propertygrid.
my class looks like this:

```
public class PropertyItem
{
    public PropertyDescription PropertyDescription { get; set; }

    [Description("the value"), Browsable(true)]
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public PropertyItem(PropertyDescription propertyDescription, object value)
    {
        PropertyDescription = propertyDescription;
        Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.PropertyDescription.Name + ": " + PropertyDescription.Type + ": " + Value;
    }
}
```

`Value` is of type `object` and this cannot be changed.
The `PropertyDescription` has the type of the `Value` and this can be anything (`string`, `int`, `bool`...)

When I set the `SelectedObject` of my `PropertyGrid`, the `Value` is always disabled.

How would I write a `TypeConverter` to convert the `object` `Value` to the `Type` in the `PropertyDescription`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to lookup and invoke a .Net TypeConverter for a particular type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956076/how-to-lookup-and-invoke-a-net-typeconverter-for-a-particular-type)

Comment: Check if [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) can help you

Comment: Displaying is not the major hangup.  But somebody, somehow, is going to have to nail down the type of the value when it is entered.  What is the type of "0" ?  This is just the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: Hi Hans, i assume that my list will include correct values and correct types.. its true what you say, but i am not considering it at the moment..thanks for the hint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a custom type converter for the property:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(PropertyValueConverter))]
public object Value { get; set; }
```

And implement it like this:

```
public class PropertyValueConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        var propItem = context.Instance as PropertyItem;
        return propItem != null && TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propItem.PropertyDescription.Type).CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType)
            || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        var propItem = context.Instance as PropertyItem;
        if (propItem != null)
            return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propItem.PropertyDescription.Type).ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        else
            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

This test code worked for me:

```
var pi = new PropertyItem(new PropertyDescription { Type = typeof(int) }, 1);
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = pi;
```

**Update:**

To support dropdown list (eg. bool):

```
    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        var propItem = context.Instance as PropertyItem;
        if (propItem != null)
            return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propItem.PropertyDescription.Type).GetStandardValues(context);
        else
            return base.GetStandardValues(context);
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        var propItem = context.Instance as PropertyItem;
        if (propItem != null)
            return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propItem.PropertyDescription.Type).GetStandardValuesSupported(context);
        else
            return base.GetStandardValuesSupported(context);
    }
```

To support custom openable properties (eg. Point):

```
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        var propItem = context.Instance as PropertyItem;
        if (propItem != null)
            return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propItem.PropertyDescription.Type).GetProperties(context, value, attributes);
        else
            return base.GetProperties(context, value, attributes);
    }

    public override bool GetPropertiesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        var propItem = context.Instance as PropertyItem;
        if (propItem != null)
            return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propItem.PropertyDescription.Type).GetPropertiesSupported(context);
        return base.GetPropertiesSupported(context);
    }
```

Comment: If i check a value of type bool, the propertygrid will show the value but not in a dropdownlist with only True or False, but it will be an empty textbox

Comment: `pi = new PropertyItem(new PropertyDescription { Type = typeof(bool) }, true);` works for me: it does not diplay empty text box and I can edit the value. To provide the dropdownlist of the bool constants override the `GetProperties` the same way.

Comment: would you mind to edit your answer above to include the GetProperties override as you said?

Comment: thank you ... i tested it with point and it works... by bool i still have some issues, it displays no dropdown list but i will check it and will let you know..thanks again