# TypeConverter and DataBinding

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, typeconverter

I'm in trouble to resolve a problem envolving convertion between radians and angle (TypeConverter).

In a Win Forms I've a TextBox with a binding to a property AngleX of a class 'Triangle'.

My property store the value in radians, but I would to show to the user in angle format, and if the user change it in the UI, I need to give it back to the class in radians.

At this point I have this code:

```
public RadAngleConverter : TypeConverter
{
   public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType == typeof(Int64);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        return  Math.PI * (Int64)value / 180.0;
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(Int64);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return (Int64)value * (180.0 / Math.PI);             
    }
}
```

In my class 'Triangle' I've this code:

```
public class Triangle()
{
...
        [TypeConverter(typeof(RadGrausFormat))] 
        public double AngleX { get; set; }
...
}
```

Finally in UI, this code:

```
...
 TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text",instanceClass,"AngleX",formattingEnable: true)
...
```

But its not working!

Someone can help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeConverter for property of Type object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633368/typeconverter-for-property-of-type-object)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `return destinationType == typeof(Int64);` and inspect the arguments. I guess it is trying to convert to string not Int64.

Comment: The program does not going to this point. I cant debug it.

Comment: Well what I would do is Create a second property with `AngleXDegrees` and bind to that instead. `public double AngleXDegrees { get {return AngleX * DegreesPerRadian;}}` then you can get on with your day!